# How to take a subset of the columns of a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a pandas data frame with multiple columns and a list with column indices (0, 1, ..., n) that index a subset of the columns of the data frame. How can I create a new data frame with exactly this subset of columns?

Comment: `df.iloc[:, list_col_index]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found in the pandas documentation:

[How do I select a subset of DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html)

The article displays many different ways to do it.